# REST delete in reality update

Tags: rest

i'm currently trying to build simple REST api with one endpoint or users looking like this:

```
GET /users - get all
GET /users/{id} - get one
POST /users - create
PUT /users/{id} - update 
DELETE /users/{id} - delete
```

The problem is with DELETE, because DELETE in reality only UPDATE `user` resource with status `REMOVED`. Is it ok? And which status should I return? I'm currently returning `202 Accepted`, as i believe that saying "Resource is accepted to be removed" is ok, but maybe there should be just `200 OK`

Answer (score 2):

When designing an API, you should always consider what the giving action means for the user of the API.

The user would not really want to know what happens behind the scenes, but only want a clean and understandable set of actions.

So for you delete action, you should consider, *"will this delete the item, from the users perspective?"*

Responding with status code 200 most often fine, but remember to send some content with it to support it.
Using many different status code for success does not really give value, so be careful.

Comment: This is what i wanted to hear. I don't want to user know that delete is my app just update resource, so he believe it's removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

RestApiTutorial says this.

> DELETE is pretty easy to understand. It is used to **delete** a
>   resource identified by a URI.
>
> On successful deletion, return HTTP status 200 (OK) along with a
>   response body, perhaps the representation of the deleted item (often
>   demands too much bandwidth), or a wrapped response (see Return Values
>   below). Either that or return HTTP status 204 (NO CONTENT) with no
>   response body. In other words, a 204 status with no body, or the
>   JSEND-style response and HTTP status 200 are the recommended
>   responses.

But you can use It for your prupose, if It do your Api logic easier to understand to the user.

I Hope It helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The question that you have to ask yourself is:

**Does the resource after the `DELETE` will still be available to the client?**

If the answer is yes then I would suggest to use a `PATCH` you can even use the [RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for that.

If the answer is no then `DELETE` is fine.

But since you have mention that the idea is to flag the `user` with a status delete I guess you have the intention to query all deleted user at some point or do something useful with it. Witch seems to be a client [admin] use case so `PATCH` sounds appropriate.

Regarding the status for `DELETE`. Some people may prefer to use the `204 No content` since you are expecting the resource to be removed.